# Use php to parse two columns of data in a text file into a key value pair array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit of a PHP noob. I have a text file with 10 comma separated pairs and I need to read them into a key=>value array.

```
3453453453,Bill Jones 
...
...
3945845746,Joe Bob
```

Into this

```
Array
(
[3453453453] => Bill Jones 
...
...
[3945845746] => Joe Bob
)
```

Here is my code so far

```
$people = array();
foreach(file('txtdatafinal') as $line)
{
list($key, $value) = explode(',' $line, 2);
$people[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($people);
```

However, even though the source file contains 10 rows, my code only gives 1 output array pair, which is always the last value in the text file.

```
Array
(
[3945845746] => Joe Bob
)
```

Even if I build two separate arrays, which will output all 10 unique values in two nice indexed arrays, and try to use array_combine I still only get the single output pair.

```
$people = array();
foreach(file('txtdatafinal') as $line)
{
list($key, $value) = explode(',' $line, 2);
$a[] = $key;
$b[] = $value;
}
$c = array_combine($a,$b);
print_r($c);

Array
(
[3945845746] => Joe Bob
)
```

My thinking is that the loop should be additive, but it seems to be replacing its key value pair each time. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `explode` is missing the separator for your arguments. It should read `explode(',', $line, 2);`. Other than that, the first code works fine for me

Comment: Good catch, that was just a typo on my part. I'm baffled as to why I only get 1 key value pair as output.

Comment: The error is certainly not your code. As I said, the first one works perfectly for me. Perhaps there are some hidden gotchas in the text file? Is it created on the fly by something? Maybe try printing the returned line (before exploding) directly in the loop to see that it's correctly pulling each line and evaluating those.

Comment: from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) "Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem."

Comment: You're right. I created a file manually vs. the one extracted from the database and my original code worked fine. Perhaps a hexdump will reveal the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so the issue was that in my source file all the KEY values were the same. 12345678, joe and 12345678, bob and so on. It seems if the keys are not unique arrays behave this way despite unique 'values'!! So, that was it. Once I made the keys unique everything worked out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of file(...) is an array, that looks like:

```
Array 
(
    0 => number, name,
    1 => number, name,
    2 => number, name,
    ...
)
```

You have to explode *$line = "number, name"* in the foreach-loop:

```
$people = array();
$lines = file("file.txt");

foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {
    $line_arr = explode(",", $line);
    $people[$line_arr[0]] = $line_arr[1];
}

print_r($people);
```

Comment: Both of these work, the issue was the source file. Note sure who to credit here...

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
$people = array();
$lines = file('txtdatafinal');
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $data = explode(',' $line);
    $key = $data[0];
    $val = $data[1];
    $people[$key] = $val;
}
print_r($people);
```

Comment: Both of these work, the issue was the source file. Note sure who to credit here...

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted it out. You can credit Peter as his answer is more complete and less verbose : )

Comment: Ok, so the issue was that in my source file all the KEY values were the same. 12345678, joe and 12345678, bob and so on. It seems if the keys are not unique arrays behave this way despite unique 'values'!! So, that was it. Once I made the keys unique everything worked out. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the line     `$data = explode(',' $line);` needs a comma before the $line variable.